# Group by multiple columns and pivot and count values from other column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
   city   skills   priority acknowledge id_count  acknowledge_count
    ABC    XXX       High      Yes         11         2
    ABC    XXX       High       No         10         3
    ABC    XXX       Med       Yes          5         1
    ABC    YYY       Low        No          1         5
```

I want to group by city and skills and get total_id_count from the column **id_count**, divided into three seperate column from **priority** as high.med,low.
SIMILARLY for total_acknowledge_count, take **acknowledge**

output required:

```
                  total_id_count      total_acknowledege_count
city,skills    High   Med   Low         Yes      No
ABC,XXX        22      5     0           3        3                # 22=11+10    3=(2+1)
ABC,YYY        0       0     1           0        5
```

I am trying different methods like pivot_table, and groupby & stack, but it seems very difficult.

Is there any way to achieve this result.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pivot separately for the `total_id_count` and the `total_acknowledege_count` here, since you have two separate `column`/`value` schemes for the aggregation:

```
piv1 = df.pivot_table(index=['city', 'skills'], columns='priority', 
                      values='id_count', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
piv2 = df.pivot_table(index=['city', 'skills'], columns='acknowledge', 
                      values='acknowledge_count', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)

piv1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['id_count'], piv1.columns])
piv2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['acknowledge_count'], piv2.columns])

output = pd.concat([piv1, piv2], axis=1)
```

---

```
print(output)

                  id_count  acknowledge_count    
                High Low Med     No Yes
city skills                                       
ABC  XXX          21   0   5     3   3
     YYY           0   1   0     5   0
```

Comment: Can you please provide the final dataframe's columns (.columns)

Comment: Because I'm getting output columns in this format: 'id_count,high','id_count,Low','id_count,Med','acknowledge_count,No','acknowledge_count,Yes'

Comment: You should get the shared output by running the above code @Shubham

Comment: The output columns is a `MultiIndex` @Shubham